# Two way ANOVA with percent change

Tags: anova, normalization, percentage, two-way

I have two groups of animals: "active cycle" and "inactive cycle".
Within each group, there are two groups: "control" and "treated".

I measured the levels of a specific receptor for each animal in each group and I ran a one-way ANOVA to see if there were significant differences between each "treated" group with respect to their corresponding "control" group.

Now I would like to see if the levels of the receptor in the exposed group of the active cycle differ with the levels seen in the exposed group of the inactive cycle.

The problem is that the "active" and "inactive" groups cannot be directly compared (meaning, I can not compare the raw data) because there was a specific variable that was changed during the experiments which made the baseline during the active cycle higher than that during the inactive cycle and I cannot know how much the baseline has increased.

So in other words, I can only compare percent changes (I think): I can compare the percent change of the treated animals over their controls in the active cycle with the percent change of the treated animals over their controls in the inactive cycle.

What kind of statistical test can I use to make this comparison?
I'm not sure if I can simply use the normalized values (as explained before) to run a two-way ANOVA.

I will attach a picture of an example of the data that I'm trying to analyze.

[image]

Comment: Could you supply a sample of the data, both raw and percent? If you have a confounding factor that is changing concurrently along with the cycle then you can't know if the resulting change is due to cycle difference or the confounding factor. You might be able to compare standardised change but it would require that the confounding effect that is changing the measures to be constant between group combinations.

Comment: I know for sure that the confounding effect is constant between all the samples of the active cycle but I don't know how big it is. Anyways I'll try to supply a sample of the data later. Thank you

Comment: Welcome to CV! Please have a look at the tour (link available if you scroll below). You need not thank others or explain your personal situation. The purpose of stackexchange is to answer questions that might also be useful for others with similar problems. Likewise, you need not excuse yourself for anything - there is no minimum level of statistical knowledge required to ask questions here. I have taken the liberty to edit out the irrelevant sections of your question and include some spacing.

Comment: That's great to hear! Thanks! Anyways I've attached a sample of the data that I'm trying to analyze.

Comment: Can you clarify how you obtained those percentages? You can compare the data from the cycles, but unless you repeat the first group's measurement (now with the confounding variable also changed), you cannot attribute how much of the change is due to the confounder and how much is due to the cycle. By the way, could you attach your data as numbers instead of a picture? This is easier to copy and more convenient for mobile users and screen readers. For analysis, it will be easier if you convert in into a single data frame with the variables: `cycle | treatment | raw_data | percent_change`.